# Find the solution to the system (not linear)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Find all $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R^3}$ satisfying:
>   $$x^2 + 4y^2 = 4xz \tag1$$
>   $$y^2 + 4z^2 = 4xy \tag2$$
>   $$z^2 + 4x^2 = 4yz \tag3$$

This is a very difficult problem. I added $-4(1) + (3)$ to get:

$$z^2 - 16y^2 = 4yz - 16xz \tag4 $$

But I get stuck after.

Answer (score 5):

$(1)+(2)+(3)\\\implies\left(x^2-4xy+4y^2\right)+\left(y^2-4yz+4z^2\right)+\left(z^2-4zx+4x^2\right)=0\\\implies(x-2y)^2+(y-2z)^2+(z-2x)^2=0\\\implies (x=2y)\land(y=2z)\land(z=2x)\\\implies x=y=z=0$

Comment: Are those the only ones/

Comment: Yes, because $x=2y=4z=8x\implies 7x=0\implies x=0$.